# Javascript onclick child

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to do a simple onclick to child elements (without jQuery):

```
document.getElementById('link').children.onclick = function(){
    this.style.color="#ff0000";
}
```

I want it to change the color to red for each element clicked. I would assume this method would work but it won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var childs = document.getElementById('link').children; //returns a HTMLCollection

for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) { // iterate over it
    childs[i].onclick = function () {   // attach event listener individually
        this.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/ak8Ks/1/)

`document.getElementById('someID').children` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so you were adding a `onclick` to a HTMLCollection, which turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a loop, if you don't want to introduce new variables, you could do:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementById('link').children, function(e) {
    e.onclick = function () {
        this.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
});
```

**[The WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ak8Ks/3/)**.